# Copying id_rsa and id_rsa.pub to another computer

Tags: ssh, docker, github

I am new to docker and ssh. I set up a deploy key for my private repo on github for ssh. Say I want to use a new computer, I would copy my id_rsa and id_rsa.pub so my new computer can git clone my private repo. But I wonder, is this the proper way to use the deploy key? Isn't id_rsa my private key and it is not supposed to copy over to other computer?

Comment: I don't think keys are related to the device that generated them.

Comment: That's why we are not to let anyone get a hold of them!

Comment: Then how are we supposed to let the other computer git clone using ssh? Isn't the point with private key and public key is that they need to match in order to gain access?